# How to add element target into my code with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I would like to open a new tab like `<a href="http://google.com"
   target="_blank">Plant 1</a>` whenever click on the Chart with
   Javascript.

**Summary:**

When you click on `Plant 1` in the Chart, a new tab with `google.com` will appear.

When you click on `Tan Thanh` in the Chart, a new tab with `dell.com` will appear.

When you click on `Plant 3` in the Chart, a new tab with `w3schools.com` will appear.

When you click on `Plant 4` in the Chart, a new tab with `simplion.com` will appear.

---

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/Qj2Rb/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 550px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'link', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['Plant 1', 'http://google.com', 1000, 400],
    ['Tan Thanh', 'http://dell.com', 1170, 460],
    ['Plant 3', 'http://w3schools.com/', 660, 1120],
    ['Plant 4', 'http://simplion.com', 1030, 540]
]);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 3]);

var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(view, options);
var selectHandler = function (e) {
    window.location = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1);
}

// Add our selection handler.
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
window.open( data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1), options.title, "height=200,width=200");
```

Instead of,

```
window.location = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0]['row'], 1);
```

Comment: That's great. However, I am looking for a new tab appears. According to your method, a new window appears.

Comment: @PMay1903 That's not possible in Js without a hack. see here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript By the way glad to help..!